# xrandr only lists mode after a while of waiting

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xrandr

I've installed arch linux a while ago on my laptop and everything worked fine. The issue I've been facing since two weeks or so (most certainly related to an update) occurs when login with external monitors attached (login runs `[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx` via `.zshrc`): `.xinitrc` runs `randrctl auto` (which is only a wrapper for `xrandr`) in order to detect the monitors connected and configure them as whished. This comes up with an error montioning that the required mode in not available for the display:

```
ERROR /usr/bin/xrandr: cannot find mode 1680x1050
```

Running xrandr staight after startup of the WM (i3 by the way) shows this output:

```
date; xrandr 
Thu Nov  5 10:15:03 CET 2015
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1600x900      60.05*+
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   ...
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2-1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 433mm x 271mm
   1440x900      59.90*+
DP2-2 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 433mm x 271mm
   1440x900      59.90*+
DP2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

That explains the error since the modes available an DP2-1 and DP2-2 are not the ones I want to apply.

After approximately 15 seconds the output changes:

```
date; xrandr 
Thu Nov  5 10:15:16 CET 2015
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1600x900      60.05*+  40.04  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   ...  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2-1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 433mm x 271mm
   1680x1050     59.95 +
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90* 
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
DP2-2 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 433mm x 271mm
   1680x1050     59.95 +
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90* 
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
DP2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Now thats as expected. How come that it takes so long and how can this be fixed?

Some additional info:

```
X.Org X Server 1.17.1
X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
Kernel: Linux 1040 4.2.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 27 08:13:28 CET 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```